# Not replacing certain variables

Tags: perl

The following section of code is working as expected...

```
create table todel (id int not null auto_increment, name varchar(100), primary key (id));
insert into todel values (NULL, '24');
select @myid:=last_insert_id();
insert into todel values (NULL, @myid);

mysql> select * from todel;
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
|  1 | 24   |
|  2 | 1    |
+----+------+
```

But the same code does not work when I try to wrap it in perl code.

```
vi myperl.pl

#!D:\Perl\bin\perl

open (output_file, ">myperl.txt");
@Program_ID = '24';
print output_file
"create table todel (id int not null auto_increment, name varchar(100), primary key (id));
insert into todel values (NULL, '@Program_ID');
select @myid:=last_insert_id();
insert into todel values (NULL, '@myid');";

close(output_file);
```

---

It generates the code as shown below. The mysql variable name @myid is missing.

```
# cat myperl.txt
create table todel (id int not null auto_increment, name varchar(100), primary key (id));
insert into todel values (NULL, '24');
select :=last_insert_id();
insert into todel values (NULL, '');
```

How do I let perl know that I do not want to replace the mysql variable? I want to replace the @Program_ID variable though.

Comment: Writing perl scripts without `use strict; use warnings;` is always a bad idea. You will get errors, but you will know what they are, and so you can fix them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
insert into todel values (NULL, '\@Program_ID');
select \@myid:=last_insert_id();
insert into todel values (NULL, '\@myid');";
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the `@` in `@myid` or Perl will treat it as the array named `myid`.

Answer (score 1):

Above your print statement, put `my @myid = 'a';` and comment out the glob `output_file` like so:

```
print # output_file
    "create...
```

Put `exit 0;` after the print statement, like so:

```
...
insert into todel values (NULL, '@myid');";
exit 0;
```

You should see this:

```
create table todel (id int not null auto_increment, name varchar(100), primary key (id));
insert into todel values (NULL, '24');
select a:=last_insert_id();
insert into todel values (NULL, a);
```

Thus, you should see the contents of the *array* `@myid` substituted for the string `@myid`.

Now comment out the declaration of `@myid`, and insert this at the top of the script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

and run it. Under 5.12 you should see:

```
Possible unintended interpolation of @myid in string at - line nn.
Possible unintended interpolation of @myid in string at - line nn.
Global symbol "@myid" requires explicit package name at - line nn.
Global symbol "@myid" requires explicit package name at - line nn.
Execution of - aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Do you think that if you had used `strict`, these errors would have told you enough? Even if you didn't understand "interpolation" googling "perl interpolation" would have helped a lot.

Now, uncomment the declaration `my @myid = 'a';`, when you run it, you'll see the same output as before, but no error messages.

What this means is that when Perl sees `$` or `@` in a *double-quote* situation (really, lookup "perl interpolation" or [`perldoc perlop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators) ) it substitutes the variable of the same name in that string. It borrows from UNIX world the idea of interpolating quotes (`"`)
 and non-interpolating quotes (`'`) and in an interpolating quote situation, you have to escape the sigil (`'$'` or `'@'`) and then Perl will treat it like the literal character.

Another thing you could do to correct the whole mess is use a non-interpolating quote *operator*. Since you use a single quote in your SQL, we can't just use single-quote to avoid interpolation. Instead we can use the `q` operator. Place `q{` at the top of the SQL and `}` at the bottom, like so:

```
print output_file
    q{create ...
    ...
    insert into todel values (NULL, @myid);
    };
```

Really, click on the perldoc link.

Answer (score 0):

Like the others said, the `@` is confusing the interpreter.  That's why it's (IMO) a good habit to single-quote a string if it doesn't include any variable interpolations.